# getnonfreefonts problem with map files

Tags: fonts, texlive

I downloaded and correctly installed the `getnonfreefonts.pl` script. I can use all the fonts without any problems. However, every time I call `tlmgr` to update my TeXLive2014 system, I get the following error:

```
updmap-sys failed (status 1), output:
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/nivaca) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     classico.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     classicovn.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     dayroman.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     garamondvn.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     ua1.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     ugm.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     ul9.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     ulg.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     webo.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     zgm.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     zpeu.map (in /root/.texlive2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.

tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

I then have to run the following command to sort things out:

```
./getnonfreefonts.pl -r
```

from my user (i.e. not `sudo`). The process completes without problems.

Is there a way to avoid doing this every time I update my system? I don't want to use the recommended `--syncwithtrees` because I want to know that everything is running fine. (I have this problem both on Ubuntu 14.10 and on Mac OS X 10.10, with TeXLive2014 and MacTeX2014 respectively.)

Comment: You should use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to begin with.

Comment: Apparently, they are the same command: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root       59 oct 30 11:19 getnonfreefonts -> ../../texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root       59 oct 30 11:19 getnonfreefonts-sys -> ../../texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl*
`

Comment: Yes, but calling them with different names has different effects.

Comment: @egreg Why?....

Comment: Look in the script itself; if called as `getnonfreefonts` it installs things in `TEXMFHOME` (not recommended), otherwise in `TEXMFLOCAL` (recommended).

Comment: OK. Thanks. If you pose it as an answer, I will approve it.

Comment: You will need to clear the effects of running `getnonfreefonts` as well. You will probably need to delete the directory `${HOME}/.texliveYYYY` where `YYYY` corresponds to your version of TeX Live (e.g. 2014) and `${HOME}` is your home directory. Otherwise, TeX will continue to try to use stale configuration files and will not recognise changes to the fonts which result from updates with `tlmgr`.

Comment: @egreg: why isn't installing things in `TEXMFHOME` recommended? Assuming one doesn't want system-wide installation.

Comment: @morbusg The problem is that updating map files with `updmap` isn't performed when some font is updated in TeX Live, which just does `updmap-sys`. Automaticall running also `updmap` is possible (for the user launching it) with TeX Live Utility on Mac OS.