# Missing getnonfreefonts-sys in MacTex 2015

Tags: fonts, mactex

I've just installed MacTeX 2015 and wanted to install the non-free fonts available with the `getnonfreefonts` Perl script. As recommended [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211483/getnonfreefonts-problem-with-map-files) in this site (see egreg's first comment), I tried calling `getnonfreefonts-sys` in order to install the fonts in `TEXMFLOCAL`, but I can't seem to find the script anywhere in my system. Am I missing a symlink or something to that end?

---

**Update:**

Of course, I have already installed `getnonfreefonts` with the Lua install script. *But I am missing the `-sys` version.*

Comment: You have to install it. The script is *not* part of TeX Live. (Unless MacTeX adds it - I don't know about that.)

Comment: See https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/.

Comment: I have already done so.

Comment: You have to do `sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts`. Just did it and `getnonfreefonts-sys` has been created in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin` and in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin`

Comment: You have to `sudo` unless you've installed so as not to require this, that is, which few people do. I just did it on GNU/Linux (without root privileges) and also got both links created correctly. However, if it is a failure to use `sudo`, as @egreg suggests, you wouldn't have the non-sys version in the local texmf tree either, would you?

Comment: @cfr I tried, but without `sudo` the script installs nothing.

Comment: @egreg Have you *installed so as not to require this*? Presumably not ;). It is safer to install TL so that it is managed by a non-privileged user. It is safest to install it so that it is managed by a dedicated non-privileged user. An error in `install-getnonfreefonts` or in `getnonfreefonts-sys` could, theoretically, wipe my installation of TeX Live and the contents of my local tree. It could not touch anything outside `/usr/local/texlive` and `/usr/local/stow-tex`. Not even the scratch file I just worked in to answer a question here. Certainly not anything in `/usr/bin` or `/etc`.

Comment: Well, thanks. That seemed to fix things. I noticed, however, that `getnonfreefonts-sys.pl` is just a symlink to `getnonfreefonts.pl`. (Although, as egreg pointed out before, the result from calling one instead of the other is different.)

Comment: @NVaughan They are different, yes. (That difference is independent of whether one needs `sudo` or not.) The script tests the name it was called as in order to determine what to do. This is quite common e.g. on most machines, `sh` is a link to another shell, often `bash` but the results of `sh` and `bash` are not the same.

Comment: [That is, on most machines on which `sh` exists. Presumably not Windows machines. But OS X and anything else Unix-y. Don't know if OS X uses `bash` specifically at the moment, though. But `sh` may well be a link to some other shell.]

Comment: @egreg Do you want to answer?